# Identity operator in quantizing electromagnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

I'd like to know what the identity operator in the canonical quantization of EM field. Here's my guess:
\begin{equation}
1=\int\frac{d^3 \vec{p}}{(2 \pi)^3}\frac{1}{2|\vec{p}|}\sum_{\lambda=0}^{3}|\vec{p}, \lambda \rangle\langle \vec{p},\lambda|
\end{equation}
But there's something wrong when I tested my guess.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|\vec{k},\lambda> &= \int \frac{d^3 \vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1} {2|\vec{p}|}\sum_{\lambda'=0}^{3}|\vec{p}, \lambda' \rangle\langle \vec{p},\lambda'|\vec{k},\lambda \rangle \\
& = \int \frac{d^3 \vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1} {2|\vec{p}|}\sum_{\lambda'=0}^{3}|\vec{p}, \lambda' \rangle\langle 0|\sqrt{2|\vec{p}|}\sqrt{2|\vec{k}|}\, a_{\vec{p}}^{\lambda'} a^{\lambda \dagger}_{\vec{k}}|0 \rangle \\
& = \int \frac{d^3 \vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3} \sqrt{\frac{|\vec{k}|} {|\vec{p}|}}\sum_{\lambda'=0}^{3}|\vec{p}, \lambda' \rangle\langle 0|[a_{\vec{p}}^{\lambda'}, a^{\lambda \dagger}_{\vec{k}}]|0 \rangle \\
& = \int \frac{d^3 \vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3} \sqrt{\frac{|\vec{k}|} {|\vec{p}|}}\sum_{\lambda'=0}^{3}|\vec{p}, \lambda'\rangle \left[-g^{\lambda\lambda'}(2\pi)^3\delta^3(\vec{p}-\vec{k}) \right] \\
& = -\sum_{\lambda'=0}^{3}g^{\lambda\lambda'}|\vec{k}, \lambda' \rangle
\end{split}
\end{equation}

This is correct when $\lambda=1,2,3$, but there's an extra minus sign when $\lambda=0$. Does any one know how to fix my guess?

Comment: *λ* =0?   .......      ?

Comment: If $\lambda = 0$, $|\vec{k},0> \rightarrow -|\vec{k},0> $ after the identity acts on it.

Comment: How did you define your polarization vectors and how many are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write
\begin{equation}
1=-\int\frac{d^3 \vec{p}}{(2 \pi)^3}\frac{1}{2|\vec{p}|}\sum_{\lambda', \lambda^{\prime\prime}} g_{\lambda' \lambda^{\prime\prime}}\, |\vec{p}, \lambda' \rangle\langle \vec{p},\lambda^{\prime\prime}| \;,
\end{equation}
then you end up with
$$ \sum_{\lambda', \lambda^{\prime\prime}} g_{\lambda' \lambda^{\prime\prime}} g^{\lambda^{\prime\prime} \lambda}\, | \vec k, \lambda' \rangle = |\vec k, \lambda \rangle \;. $$
Note that this is only the identity operator on the 1-particle subspace of the Fock space (the Fock space before imposing the Gupta-Bleuler condition!).